# Accessing IIFE function variables

Tags: javascript

I have a function defined and executed as such ..

```
var exitPopup = (function($) {
  var someVar = false;
  var someFunc = function() { doSomething(); };
})(jQuery);
```

My question is, is it possible to access the variables and functions within? How can I call `someFunc` without modifying the above code (its a plugin)?

I would think something like

```
exitPopup.someFunc();
```

But yeah, no..

Comment: Thats an IIFE, so I dont think you can access any of those variables.

Comment: No i dont think you can do that

Comment: In that exact example, you can't. but many plugins offer ways of extending them, such as making the functions available on a property of window or whatever global is in your environment.

Comment: It looks like this code was written to _prevent_ you from accessing those variables...

Comment: The purpose of immediately invoked function expressions (`(function(){...})()`) is to *protect* the code inside and don't expose variables to parent scopes (for instance window).

Comment: Dang... thanks for all the insight

Comment: Not even something like `exitPopup.someFunc();` because the IIFE is not returning anything, `exitPopup` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the MDN docs of IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE),

> IIFE is a design pattern which is also known as Self-Executing Anonymous Function and contains two major parts. The first is the anonymous function with lexical scope enclosed within the Grouping Operator (). **This prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope.**

So, no it cannot be accessed.